# How is this 'if statement' incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to write an if statement in a dropdown menu that when clicked, will display the options "delete" and "edit" for the user who owns the post. While it will show the options "report post" and "block user" for all other users.

I added this to my **posts controller** and it works correctly.

```
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if current_user == @post.user
        @post.destroy
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

I created this if statement in my dropdown and it does not work correctly. I tried to delete a post I own and seen "Report post", I then tried to delete another user's post and still seen "Report post". It's suppose to show me "Delete" when I try to delete my own posts.

```
<ul>
  <% if current_user == @post.user %>
    <li><%= link_to 'Delete post', post, :method => :delete %></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><a href"#">Report post</a></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure `current_user.id` and `@post.user.id` match?

Comment: What is `current_user` equal to? Are you signed in?

Comment: `if current_user == @post.user` works in my posts controller. How can I check? Shema?

Comment: Yes, I am signed in and I created many posts with different users (for testing). They all say 'report post'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error here:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Delete post', post, :method => :delete %></li>
```

and you need that:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Delete post', @post, :method => :delete %></li>
```

or here:

```
<% if current_user == @post.user %>
```

and you need that:

```
<% if current_user == post.user %>
```

Comment: This works, but now I am seeing the error: `No route matches [DELETE] "/posts"`. Sorry, I'm new to rails. How do I fix this? When I rake routes, I see: `DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy`

Comment: try this:
`<%= link_to 'Delete post', post_path(post), method: :delete %>` if still get eror you have something error in your `post`

Comment: That solved the problem. I wasn't sure why that was happening because it worked before. lol